# SSIS - Comparing text file and non oledb connection to give matched and non matched output

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have 2 inputs. One is text file and the other is proprietary DB which is basically non oledb connection. I would like to compare both these datasets and give me 2 outputs matched and non matched. I can use merge join but it gives only one output. For lookup I may need to load the text file data into SQL server to give me 2 outputs as required. I would like to avoid the extra step of loading data into SQL server. Please let me know the simplest way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you do to get the result set you have? Please edit your post to give those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the Merge Join using an Outer Join, so that rows that don't match will have a NULL column in the output.

Then do a conditional split and send the rows with NULLs to the non-matched output, and the rows with NOT NULL to the matched output.

Comment: Thanks. Yes that worked. My bad. Looking for a component in SSIS.